# Not able to add 2 toolbars in Kendogrid ?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I already have one toolbar for filtering the grid.

I need one more toolbar for excel. Both should be on the header of the grid.

```
var grid = $("#grid_View").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: datasource,
           selectable: "row",
           sortable: true, editable: false,
           toolbar: kendo.template($("#filterTemplate").html()),
           toolbar: ["excel"],
           excel: {
               fileName: "LogExport.xls",
               filterable: true
           },
```

Filter template is in the grid html:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="filterTemplate">
            <div class="toolbar">
                <label  id="fromRange"></label>
                <label>@CommonResource.From</label>
                <label id="logFromDate"></label>
                <label>@CommonResource.To</label>
                <label id="logToDate"></label>

                <input type="search" id="events" />
            </div>
        </script>
```

Comment: Try this one `kendo.template($("#filterTemplate1").html() + $("#filterTemplate2").html())` OR <div class="toolbar"></div><div class="toolbar"></div>. might be helpful.

Comment: I have the excel toolbar which I can't remove. There is no filterTemplate1 and filterTemplate2

Comment: then you are looking for this http://www.telerik.com/forums/default-create-command-in-toolbar-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your excel template in your "filterTemplate"

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="filterTemplate">
  <div class="toolbar">
    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-pdf" href="\\#">
        <span class=" ">
        </span>pdf
    </a>
    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="\\#">
        <span class=" ">
        </span>excel
    </a>
    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add" href="\\#">
        <span class="k-icon k-add">
        </span>Add new record
    </a>
    <label  id="fromRange"></label>
    <label>@CommonResource.From</label>
    <label id="logFromDate"></label>
    <label>@CommonResource.To</label>
    <label id="logToDate"></label>

    <input type="search" id="events" />
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Its working fine.. Thanks a lot for your help. But one issue I marked is the Date column shows wrong value in the excel file. In pdf file the Date is correctly displayed.